Trying to get treesitter indents to work with multiple languages for a major mode
I am working on a major mode using treesitter as my parser. It's been pretty intuitive but I ran into an issue. When trying to use multiple languages, you have to specify ranges using nodes in the AST it generates. The set ranges seem to work for syntax-coloring but not indenting correctly as it tries to find an indent rule in the host language.
    (defvar language_a-ts-range-rules
      '(:embed language_b
        :host language_a
        ((method_body (method_body_content) @capture))))

This is how I'm capturing the ranges to use the embedded language parser. And then later I do this:
    (setq-local treesit-range-settings
              (apply #'treesit-range-rules
                     language_a-ts-range-rules))

to apply those rules to my major mode.
My indent rules look like
        (setq-local treesit-simple-indent-rules
        '((language_a
         ((parent-is "program") parent 0) ;More rules follow ...
           ;; When indenting in language_b, it tries to find a rule here.
          )
          (language_b
          ((parent-is "command_set") parent 4) ;More rules follow ...
          )))

I can't find any real-world examples of a multi-language indent rules list but I extrapolated from the manual so that could be wrong.
I tried flipping the order I create the parsers but this just causes it to recognize language_b when indenting and not language_a. This is strange considering the syntax highlighting works both on the embedded language and host language. For example:
        (define-derived-mode language_a-ts-mode prog-mode "language_a"
      "Major mode for editing 'language_a, powered by tree-sitter"
      (when (and (treesit-ready-p 'language_a) (treesit-ready-p 'language_b))
        (treesit-parser-create 'language_a) ;flipping these two flips which 
         (treesit-parser-create 'language_b);indent rules are recognized
        (language_a-ts-setup)))

This is more about ELisp and tree-sitter than the specific language. Let me know if I need to provide anymore information.

This answer might be a bit late, but you need to set treesit-language-at-point-function so Emacs knows which parser should it use for a give point. It's mandatory for a multi-language major mode to set it, because Emacs has no way to guess it.
